# Cannot reuse a function for quill SQL filtering

Tags: sql, scala, function, reusability, quill.io

I have a case class Employee

```
 case class Employee(id: Int, 
                     name: String, 
                     age: Int, is_permanent: Boolean, 
                     company_name: String)
```

I am filtering on this Employee case class using Quill SQL like this:

```
quote {
  query[Employee]
    .filter(e => e.age > 100)
    .filter(e => liftQuery(List("Robin, Peter")).contains(e.name))
}
```

It compiles fine.

Now I want to put the second `filter` into a function and reuse it.
Like

```
  val employeeQueryFunc: (Employee => Boolean) = e => {
    liftQuery(List("Robin, Peter")).contains(e.name)
  }
```

and then apply this function at multiple locations wherever I need. If I put this to the employee query like this

```
 quote {
  query[Employee]
    .filter(e => e.age > 100)
    .filter(employeeQueryFunc)
}
```

It does not compile. I get the error

```
  this.Employee]).filter(((e: FindAllIssuesRepoQuery.this.Employee) => e.age.> . 
  (100))).filter(employeeQueryFunc)' can't be parsed to 'Ast'
```

Ideally it should have compiled as the filter block also contains a function that returns a boolean and `employeeQueryFunc` also returns a boolean. Does anyone know how it can be reused as a function ??

Answer (score 1):

had a similar issue - have experimented with Daniel's suggestion and in my case it was enough to rewrite

```
quote {
  query[Employee]
    .filter(e => e.age > 100)
    .filter(employeeQueryFunc)
}
```

into:

```
quote {
  query[Employee]
    .filter(e => e.age > 100)
    .filter(e => employeeQueryFunc(e))
}
```

(no idea why)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when trying to extract a common logic to a private method.
update the employeeQueryFunc to:

```
private def employeeQueryFunc = quote {
    (e: Employee) => liftQuery(List("Robin, Peter")).contains(e.Name)
}
```

and call this method the following way:

```
quote {
  query[Employee]
    .filter(e => e.age > 100)
    .filter(e => employeeQueryFunc(e))
}
```